# Bluetooth audio sink [sic] refuses to connect in Ubuntu 14.04 (bluez, blueman)

Tags: 14.04, sound, bluetooth, pulseaudio, a2dp

Bluetooth just absolutely refuses to connect to any audio sinks. I've tried with two separate speakers that I can pair with just fine on iOS, yet when I try, I get this error in blueman:

Connection Failed: DBusFailedError: Protocol not available...

It doesn't even show up in pulseaudio (probably because I can't connect).

I've googled and come across tons of "solutions" that never work. I've honestly tried so many, I forget what I've even tried.

This is important to me because I set up Ubuntu for the purpose of having a HTPC, yet it's lacking functionality to connect with Bluetooth speakers. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I just want to share my experience with bluetooth problems under Linux Mint 17.2, 17.3 and 18. Problem was my card (Broadcom BCM4352) and bcmwl-kernel-source driver which didn't work very well. I spent hours of trying to get BT running. Wifi also has connection aborts from time to time. So I bought INTEL AC8260 combo card and everything works like a charm. "pactl load-module module-bluetooth-policy" and
"pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover" worked for me now. Thanks!

Comment: `[sic]` is usually meant to indicate an error reproduced as-is.  But "sink" is the correct term here, not an error.  A bluetooth audio "sink" is something that *receives* bluetooth audio.  This is bluetooth standard terminology, and it distinguishes the device that receives bluetooth audio from the device that sends it.

Answer (score 7):

In my case, this was solved by using these two commands:

```
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-policy 
pactl load-module module-bluetooth-discover
```

Comment: Your first command gave me "Failure: Module initialization failed", but the second command made it possible for me to connect to my BT headphones as 'audio sink'; formerly they would only connect as 'headset service', which wasn't any use to me.

Answer (score 1):

Might want to check you have `pulseaudio-module-bluetooth` installed. I was having trouble until I found [this post on GitHub](https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/547) Not saying this is an answer to this specific problem but just to make sure.

```
sudo apt-get install pulseaudio-bluetooth
killall pulseaudio
```

Comment: command here was:
`sudo apt install pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

sudo /etc/init.d/bluetooth restart

pulseaudio -k

pulseaudio --start

Then go to the audio manager, and make sure the program that's generating audio has the Bluetooth "sink" as output.

Reference link - https://github.com/blueman-project/blueman/issues/304

Comment: Doesn't fix it, nor do I see how it would. The problem isn't with PulseAudio, it's with Bluetooth. It says, after I've gone through "Add new device," that it was "Added successfully but failed to connect."