# "Audio Sync" not working with bluetooth speakers

Tags: 16.04, xubuntu, bluetooth, bluez, blueman

The issue I have is that, when trying to connect my bluetooth to my laptop (under *Xubuntu 16.04*), the speakers pair well, but once they are paired, I go on to click on "Audio sink", and I immediately get this error message :

```
Connection Failed: blueman.bluez.errors.DBusFailedError: Protocol not available.
```

I have tried every solution I found online but none of them work, thank you if have a solution to this problem :)

Comment: Please add the output of: `apt --installed list | grep pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`, and then have a look at [Bluetooth module for PulseAudio sound server](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/pulseaudio-module-bluetooth/) and [Arch - Bluetooth headset](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Bluetooth_headset#Headset_via_Bluez5.2FPulseAudio), and lastly [Pulseaudio not detecting bluetooth headset automatically](http://askubuntu.com/questions/366032/pulseaudio-not-detecting-bluetooth-headset-automatically)

Comment: After the two commands you said I found I didn't have pulseaudio-module-bluetooth installed, so I installed it but it didn't change anything. I had already tried the solutions from the threads you mentionned.

Comment: Then install all the items listed in the Arch link.  More than one is missing, and then retry.

Comment: When I try to install them, I get " Unable to locate package [package] " with all of them except for the the package 'bluez'. I suppose I have to add a repository, but which one? Thank you.

Comment: While I look up the equivalent packages for Ubuntu, do the `pactl` commands in [Bluetooth audio sink refuses to connect in Ubuntu 14.04 (bluez, blueman)](http://askubuntu.com/questions/768250/bluetooth-audio-sink-refuses-to-connect-in-ubuntu-14-04-bluez-blueman) help or have you tried these?

Comment: Both of these commands get me the message "Failure: Module initialization failed". Thanks for taking the time to help me by the way :)

Comment: Please provide and do the information I've requested of you in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's start here, as these comments are getting out of control.  I'll provide what I need, and you can either edit my Answer, or edit your question.  I realize PulseAudio and bluetooth aren't necessarily related, but I want to make sure that all the other pieces are properly *fresh*.

### Starting With A Clean Slate

Let's clean out PulseAudio's Configuration and Installation so we all start on a clean slate:

1. If you are using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS (Precise Pangolin) or later, try this first: `killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.config/pulse/* ; rm -r ~/.pulse*`
2. Issue: `pulseaudio -k`
3. [Remove your particular desktop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/789456/ubuntu-falls-back-to-old-window-style-on-every-second-boot/790834?noredirect=1#comment1193300_790834), in case you aren't using the default desktop.  Sorry, but I need a Baseline. Stop after the clean command.  Before rebooting, let's remove PulseAudio.  See Step 4.
4. To remove and reinstall PulseAudio issue: `` sudo apt-get update;sudo apt-get dist-upgrade; sudo apt-get install pavucontrol linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; sudo apt-get -y --reinstall install linux-sound-base alsa-base alsa-utils lightdm ubuntu-desktop  linux-image-`uname -r` libasound2; killall pulseaudio; rm -r ~/.pulse*; ubuntu-support-status ``
5. Disconnect all Bluetooth devices.
6. Reboot.
7. Reinstall Unity, and Ubuntu Desktop.  See the last of the post I linked in Step 3.  At this point, you should have audio in hardware speakers.
8. Enable Unlimited Scrolling in your Terminal:  Start a new terminal, and click `Edit > Profiles > "Default" profile > Scrolling. Choose "Unlimited" as scrolling option. Click Close and Close again.`
9. Verify or add your user to the following groups using `usermod -aG`: **pulse**, **audio**, **pulse-access**, **pulse-rt**, **video**:
   `` cat /etc/group | grep -e '^pulse:' -e '^audio:' -e '^pulse-access:' -e '^pulse-rt:' -e '^video:' | awk -F: '{print $1}' | tr '\n' ',' | sed 's:,$::g'` `whoami ``

### Provide Information About ALSA and PulseAudio

1. Download the ALSA script: `wget -O alsa-info.sh http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-info.sh && chmod +x ./alsa-info.sh && ./alsa-info.sh`.
2. Provide information here about ALSA: `bash alsa-info.sh --stdout`.
3. Provide the following information about your devices: `cat /proc/asound/{version,cards,devices,hwdep,pcm,seq/clients}; sudo rm /etc/asound.conf; sudo rm -r ~/.pulse ~/.asound* ;sudo rm ~/.pulse-cookie; sudo apt-get update; sudo apt-get install aptitude; sudo aptitude install paman gnome-alsamixer libasound2-plugins padevchooser libsdl1.2debian-pulseaudio; sudo lshw -short;ls -lart /dev/snd; find /lib/modules/`uname -r`| grep snd ;cat /dev/sndstat; lspci -nn; lsusb; sudo which alsactl; sudo fuser -v /dev/dsp /dev/snd/* ; dpkg -S bin/slmodemd; dmesg | egrep 'EMU|probe|emu|ALSA|alsa|ac97|udi|snd|ound|irmware'; sudo /etc/init.d/sl-modem-daemon status; sudo grep model /etc/modprobe.d/* ; sudo dmidecode|egrep 'anufact|roduct|erial|elease'; lsmod | egrep 'snd|usb|midi|udio'; pacmd list-sinks; aplay -l; sudo alsa force-reload;  ubuntu-support-status ; sudo lshw -C sound`
4. Provide a PulseAudio startup log: `sudo gedit /etc/pulse/client.conf`.  Add `extra-arguments = -vvvv --log-target=newfile:/tmp/pulseverbose.log --log-time=1` to the End of the file.  Reboot && Post the content of the log here.

### Provide Information on Bluetooth Applications

1. `apt-cache policy pulseaudio`.
2. `apt-cache policy bluez`.
3. `apt-cache policy blueman`.
4. `apt-cache policy pulseaudio-module-bluetooth`.
5. Verify your Ubuntu release: `lsb_release -rd`
6. Post the contents of `/etc/pulse/default.pa`.

---

### References

[UbuntuWiki - SoundTroubleshootingProcedure](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SoundTroubleshootingProcedure)
[PulseAudio Bug 1274613 - LaunchPad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pulseaudio/+bug/1274613)
[UbuntuWiki - PulseAudio Logging](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/PulseAudio/Log)
[Ubuntu Forums - (Solved) module-bluetooth-discover not loading on startup](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2194428)

Answer (score 0):

I followed [this](https://zach-adams.com/2014/07/bluetooth-audio-sink-stream-setup-failed/), and it worked even though it wouldn't work multiple times. I think it is because I didn't properly close every program involved (blueman/pulseaudio) before executing the command

Comment: See Step 6 of my Answer below in Provide Information on Bluetooth Applications, and I think I can get you a fix.

Comment: What I meant was I think I found a permanent solution, thanks a lot for your help though